# jHa, Ala, GMa, etc. in Firebase Analytics. display of events

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics in my Flutter project. I am triggering the names of my pages with runtimeType as an event for firebase analytics. jHa, Ala, GMa etc. in RealTime. events appear. But this way I don't have page names. I don't know where these events came from. Can you help me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The page_view is collected by default for Web apps. Analytics will log the text contents of a web page's  tag or the value can be sent explicitly with a screen_name property.

Also, these events could be logged in the viewDidAppear state for Apple and onResume for Android. Do note that, when screen_class is not set, Analytics sets a default value based on the UIViewController or Activity that is in focus when the call is made. You can read this [blogpost](https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view) for more details on how to apply it.

You may opt to [disable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#disable_screenview_tracking) automatic screenview reporting by the following:

For iOS - set **FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled** to **NO** (Boolean) in the *Info.plist*.

For Android - nest the following setting within the  tag of the *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

[image]